# display image from camera roll in imageView.image not working Xcode objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an app that I want to select an image from the photoLibrary using UIImagePicker and then display it in a UIImageView.image.  It was working not too long ago but now it is not.  When I tap on the image I want nothing happens and I get the warning

[Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error

Here is the code I am using that worked before.

```
-(IBAction)saveIMAGE:(id)sender{


    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];



}
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

  UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    self.RealImage.image = chosenImage;
     [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Like I said it was working great not too long ago but now nothing.

I see there is a lot of discussion about this, but I haven't found anything that works.

Do I need to save it as a temp file and then load it?

I think it must be a bug that Apple needs to fix.

Any ideas, suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What warning you received ?

Comment: i put it above in my post.  Here it is again  [Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error

Answer (score 0):

You can use these delegate method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)selectedImage editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
 UIImage *chosenImage = selectedImage;

    self.RealImage.image = chosenImage;
     [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: I believe he/she need `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` so this answer might not be helpful.

Comment: The above post didn't work.  RealImage is NOT a IBOutlet. It has been populated with images though.  To try something else I created IBOutlet imageView below RealImage.  When I select an image in the photoLibrary it does show up in the New IBOutlet imageView but all the rest of the buttons on the page are disabled and if I try to use a touchMoved to draw on other image views nothing happens and I get this error   <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.  Why should picking image do this?

Answer (score 0):

I had to save the image view image to documents directory and then set the image to nothing when the image picker view is called and then reload it from documents directory when viewdidload is called when imagepicked is released. Solved the problem